# Simultaneous touches on scene

Tags: touch, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am having one problem while working on touches on the screen. I have two modules attached on the screen, on the Left there is a Joystick which has its own touches, and on the right side I have set of Buttons which have its own actions or, touches, both doesn't work together. I have tried to setup touches instead of callbacks on buttons, and tried replacing the buttons with sprites without any luck.

See my requirement below

[image]

Any help or, suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

**See my code below** what I have tried

I am using **`SneakyJoystick`** for the joystick like below

```
void Game::prepareJoystick(){
    Size winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();

    Rect joystickBaseDimensions;
    joystickBaseDimensions = Rect(0, 0, 160.0f, 160.0f);

    Point joystickBasePosition;
    joystickBasePosition = Vec2(winSize.width*0.08, winSize.height*0.15);

    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = new SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase();
    joystickBase->init();
    joystickBase->setPosition(joystickBasePosition);
    joystickBase->setBackgroundSprite(CCSprite::create("iphone-joystick.png"));
    joystickBase->setThumbSprite(CCSprite::create("iphone-joystick_cursor.png"));

    SneakyJoystick *aJoystick = new SneakyJoystick();
    aJoystick->initWithRect(joystickBaseDimensions);
    aJoystick->autorelease();
    joystickBase->setJoystick(aJoystick);
    joystickBase->setPosition(joystickBasePosition);

    leftJoystick = joystickBase->getJoystick();
    leftJoystick->retain();
    this->addChild(joystickBase);
    joystickBase->setScale(GameConfig::controlScale());

}
```

And for controls on the right hand side I am using cocos2d::ui::Buttons with their callbacks like below

```
Button *button=Button::create(imageName);
button->setTouchEnabled(true);
button->setPressedActionEnabled(true);
button->addClickEventListener(callback);
button->setPosition(position);
```

Both are added on the same scene like I shown in the **image graphics**. Now both doesn't work together. One blocks another, I tried to add touches delegates and try see my code below

```
auto listener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();

listener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(Game::onTouchesBegan, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

and handling like below

```
void GameScene::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event){
    for(int i=0;i<touches.size();i++){

        Vec2 touchLocation=touches.at(i)->getLocation();

        if(btnPunch->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(touchLocation)){
            printf("\nshould punch");
            punchCallbackAction(this);
        }

    }

}
```

None of above method works for me.

**Update 2**

Just tested the code below **returns always 1**

```
void GameScene::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches, Event *unused_event){
    printf("\nTouches = %d",(int)touches.size());
}
```

**Update 3**

**`Multitouch`** is enabled for cocos2dx see below

```
bool GLViewImpl::initWithRect(const std::string& viewName, Rect rect, float frameZoomFactor)
{
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    convertAttrs();
    CCEAGLView *eaglview = [CCEAGLView viewWithFrame: r
                                       pixelFormat: (NSString*)_pixelFormat
                                       depthFormat: _depthFormat
                                preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                        sharegroup: nil
                                     multiSampling: NO
                                   numberOfSamples: 0];

    [eaglview setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    _screenSize.width = _designResolutionSize.width = [eaglview getWidth];
    _screenSize.height = _designResolutionSize.height = [eaglview getHeight];
//    _scaleX = _scaleY = [eaglview contentScaleFactor];

    _eaglview = eaglview;

    return true;
}
```

**Update 3 `GLView initialization`**

```
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();

 if(!glview) {
     glview = GLViewImpl::create("MyGame");
     director->setOpenGLView(glview);
 }
```

There is no `Multitouch property` for above initialization, do I need to do it in different way ?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have updated my code, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: You're looking at the CCGLViewImpl-ios.mm it looks like.  That's not where you turn multi-touch on.  It's in the AppController.mm file where you need to enable the multi-touch because it is set to NO by default for IOS.

Comment: @microslop See my Update 3 for initialization, can you please help?

Comment: @microslop Oh my I didn't know there is a `AppController.mm`, it works now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If testing on iOS, The `multipleTouchEnabled` property needs to be set to **`YES`** before the view can accept multitouch.

In your `AppController.mm`, look for function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and add following line

```
[eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled: true];
```

Comment: I was looking into a wrong place for `multipleTouchEnabled`, I had to enable it in AppController.mm file, Can you please complete your answer?